# Google Sheets API - Python - Creating a Sheet

Tags: google-sheets-api, google-api-python-client

I am new to API's and i am trying to create a google sheet using python. I am able to create google sheet but unable to view/edit(Access issue). I am using Service Account in API's. Please help me in modifying the code to access the created sheets.

Here is the sample code i am using to create one.

```
service = discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)

spreadsheet_body = {
}

request = service.spreadsheets().create(body=spreadsheet_body)
response = request.execute()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "view it"? Which scopes do you have? Please provide your full code including authentication and service account builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Most likely you are creating the sheet as the service account - by default on its Drive, this is why you have issues accessing it.
- If instead you want to create a sheet on YOUR drive, you need to use impersonation:
- After [enabling domain-wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation#delegate_domain-wide_authority_to_your_service_account), you need to impersonate the service account as you.
- In python you can do it by specifying `credentials = credentials.create_delegated(user_email)` when [instantiating the service object](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation#instantiate_an_admin_sdk_directory_service_object).

Comment: Thanks for your help!